# Is it possible to upload svg file into Dynamics CRM webresource in on-premise version (8.1)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to upload SVG files into a web resource on-premise version (8.1). But I can't see any option to choose Vector Format from the resource type dropdown.

Is it possible?

Comment: What did you endup with?

Comment: I have converted all svg to png to support both 8.x and 9.x

Comment: @Hey could you please mark Arun's Answer as Solved. This will help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this, as the SVG support added in v9 only and v8.1 doesn't support it.

> Vector Format (SVG) web resources were added with the Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement apps version 9.0.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/image-web-resources)

Comment: How can I use my existing svg files then?

Comment: @Hey can you not convert them into .png or .jpg to use it..? I know whats svg but your CRM version doesnt support it yet